# indexing jsonb arrays and query jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

```
[{"id": "345", "categoryid": "2", "products": ["23", "45","34"]}]
[{"id": "2343", "categoryid": "3", "products":  ["123", "455"]}]
[{"id": "12", "categoryid": "12", "products":  ["234", "459","314","4563"]}, {"id": "512", "categoryid": "15", "products":  ["234"]}]
[{"id": "123", "categoryid": "3", "products":  ["293", "145","634"]}, {"id": "889", "categoryid": "18", "products":  ["123", "845","1234"]}]
[{"id": "2546", "categoryid": "2", "products":  ["2397", "452","434","234", "479","304","4563"]}]


SELECT *
FROM   products p,
       jsonb_array_elements(p.products_rec_jsonb) elem
WHERE  (elem ->> 'id')::bigint < 1234
       AND
       (
         (
           (elem -> 'products') ?| array(12,576,34)::text[]
           AND
           (elem -> 'categoryid') ?| array(12,5)::text[]
         )
         OR
         (elem -> 'categoryid') ?| array(12,5)::text[]
       )
ORDER BY (elem ->> 'id')::bigint DESC
LIMIT 20;

CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_products_products ON products  USING GIN (products_rec_jsonb -> 'products')  

CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_products_category ON products  USING GIN (products_rec_jsonb -> 'categoryid')  

CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_products_id ON products  USING BTREE (products_rec_jsonb ->> 'id')
```

I need to make this query use indexes(on jsonb column `products_rec_jsonb`) like `"products"`,`"categoryid"` and  `"id"`.

I wanna index `"products"` and `"category_id"` as GIN and `"id"` as BTREE DESC (as bigint data type)  ...The problem is when i run query it doesnt use indexes at all.How can i fix it?

Comment: Your query won't use your indexes, because you manually unwind your JSON array (with `jsonb_array_elements`). -- *Some* parts of your query *could* make use of a single, GIN index on the whole `products_rec_jsonb` column (if you refactor your query to use the containment operators, i.e. `<@` or `@>`). Though, the parts, like `WHERE (elem ->> 'id')::bigint < 1234` and `ORDER BY (elem ->> 'id')::bigint` will never be index-able with GIN.

Comment: thanks for the answer...i especially need 'id' to be indexed:(( is it really impossible to do that?

Comment: with your current schema, it is. you could re-design your tables to have a junction table (with one-to-many relation to your original table), which could hold the JSON array *elements* (rather than the full array). That would be index-able.

Comment: that sounds like a good option...